# ANTLR grammar : Understand CP1252 euro character

Tags: php, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

My grammar is a simple one but I want it to accept some strings in order to make concatenation. This formula has to be valid :

```
CONCATENATE(10;" €" )
```

The problem is that euro symbol. I used to but this into my grammar, this was working very good for the degree symbol :

```
fragment SPECIAL        :   '\u00B0';
```

But the euro symbol is not working like this degree symbol :

```
fragment SPECIAL        :   '\u00B0' | '\u20AC'
```

I'm generating a PHP parser with ANTLR 3.4 and the lexer code generated is the following for the degree symbol :

```
$this->getToken('176')== $LA26 || ...
```

And it should ad this for the euro symbol, If I add it manually after parser generation (there are 2 places to add it), it works !

```
$this->getToken('128')== $LA26 || ...
```

My question is : How to add it in the grammar to get this code generation ? Is there a problem with this range of unicode symbols, starting with something wlse than u00... because all my other SPECIAL characters are starting with \u00

Thanks a lot for the time spent with me.
Sincerely
Nicolas.

Comment: Encode EVERYTHING as UTF-8!

Comment: please stop trolling, antlr php doesn't support utf8

Comment: oh! really?! no trolling at all my friend!

Comment: according to this it does! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549393/antlr4-doesnt-correctly-recognizes-unicode-characters

Comment: @delboy1978uk that question is about ANTLR 4 though - not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: I use Antlr 3, 4 is different

Answer (score 1):

If your parser uses CP1252 input, how do you expect it to work with tokens defined in terms of Unicode code points?

If the input is CP1252, you need to use that charset's code points. Use `\u0080` for euro sign in CP1252.

Comment: I'll give 0080 a try. But passing unicode points works for u00B0 the degree or Number symbol... That's why I can't figure out where is the problem...

Comment: 0xB0 is code point for degree in both Unicode and CP1252, that might be the reason.